# JSHint and jQuery: '$' is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, lint, jshint

The following JS:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("#target").click(function(){
    console.log("clicked");
  });

}());
```

Yields:

```
test.js: line 5, col 3, '$' is not defined.
```

When linted using JSHint 0.5.5.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added `jquery.js` to your page?

Comment: Well, if you feed it just that code by itself, `$` **is** undefined.

Comment: I have this problem in angular. Just change $ to angular.element and jshint no warn

Answer (score 391, accepted):

If you are using a relatively recent version of JSHint, the generally preferred approach is to create a .jshintrc file in the root of your project, and put this config in it:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "$": false
    }
}
```

This declares to JSHint that $ is a global variable, and the false indicates that it should not be overridden.

The .jshintrc file was not supported in really old versions of JSHint (such as v0.5.5 like the original question in 2012). If you cannot or do not want to use the .jshintrc file, you can add this at the top of the script file:

```
/*globals $:false */
```

There is also a shorthand "jquery" jshint option as seen on the [JSHint options page](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/)..

Comment: This option, jquery, simply defines two read-only global variables: $ and jQuery. It is a shorter version of `/*global $:false, jQuery:false */`.

Comment: With my JSHint for Visual Studio, the option is called "assume jQuery"

Comment: The option flag is the way to go.For first timers: add the line 'jquery: true' in your .jshintrc file.

Comment: What is the reason for ":false"?, I found /*global $ */ works just fine. (In my case in was /*global jQuery */ though)

Comment: is there a way to set this generically for all functions within a script, rather than type one by one in `/* global ... */`? I typically import a script with all my functions into my `main` so it is cumbersome to define one by one...

Answer (score 154):

You can also add two lines to your .jshintrc

```
  "globals": {
    "$": false,
    "jQuery": false
  }
```

This tells jshint that there are two global variables.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. polluting EVERY SINGLE javascript FILE in your project with various lines of code to make the a syntax checker happy is not an option. Thanks wmil

Answer (score 54):

All you need to do is set `"jquery": true` in your `.jshintrc`.

Per the [JSHint options reference](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#jquery):

> #### jquery
>
> This option defines globals exposed by the jQuery JavaScript library.

Comment: This should probably be the top answer... shame it's buried down here

Comment: Where to find .jshintrc file in Sublime text 3 ? I tried to put this option in SublimeLinter.sublime-settings file (Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings-Default) and also tried to make new .jshintrc file (my.jshintrc) in my project root directory, according to http://jshint.com/docs/. Non of this helped me.

Comment: @Milos Install JSHint Gutter in sublimetext 3. Go to Tools > JSHint > Set Linting Preferences, It'll open .jshintrc.

Comment: Nothing again, it still cannot recognizes "$" sign. When I open .jshintrc it is on path:   \AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\JSHint Gutter, I put  "jquery": true and nothing happens.

Comment: Much better answer than adding variables to the globals section! Solve it this way!

Answer (score 17):

Here is a happy little list to put in your .jshintrc 
I will add to this list at time passes.

```
{
  // other settings...
  // ENVIRONMENTS
  // "browser": true, // Is in most configs by default
  "node": true,
  // others (e.g. yui, mootools, rhino, worker, etc.)
  "globals": {
    "$":false,
    "jquery":false,
    "angular":false
    // other explicit global names to exclude
  },
}
```

Comment: If you set the "browser" and "node" options to "true", the only remaining items in this list that are necessary are $, jquery, and angular. For more info, see the Environment section of the docs: http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#environments

Comment: I've edited the answer to include your update thank you @user456584

Answer (score 9):

If you're using an IntelliJ editor such as WebStorm, PyCharm, RubyMine, or IntelliJ IDEA:

In the Environments section of File/Settings/JavaScript/Code Quality Tools/JSHint, click on the jQuery checkbox.

Comment: Pay attention as well that you can override all inner configurations by checking "use config file". This will make WS see the config file modifications. Without it he just ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of recommending the usual "turn off the JSHint globals", I recommend using the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) to fix this problem. It keeps your code "contained" and gives a performance boost (based on Paul Irish's ["10 things I learned about Jquery"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_qE1iAmjFg)).

I tend to write my module patterns like this:

```
(function (window) {
    // Handle dependencies
    var angular = window.angular,
        $ = window.$,
        document = window.document;

    // Your application's code
}(window))
```

You can get these other performance benefits (explained more [here](http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern)):

- When minifying code, the passed in `window` object declaration gets minified as well. e.g. `window.alert()` become `m.alert()`.
- Code inside the self-executing anonymous function only uses 1 instance of the `window` object.
- You cut to the chase when calling in a `window` property or method, preventing expensive traversal of the scope chain e.g. `window.alert()` (faster) versus `alert()` (slower) performance.
- Local scope of functions through "namespacing" and containment (globals are evil). If you need to break up this code into separate scripts, you can make a submodule for each of those scripts, and have them imported into one main module.

Comment: This is a pattern I use as well, but it does not solve the original problem for me. JSHint still complains that a variable is not defined on the last line (`"}(window))`" in your example -- I had issues also with jQuery and Highcharts). I haven't found a way to turn it off other than defining a global for the file, which then defeats the purpose.

Comment: @myrosia `browser: true` tells JSHint that you expect a browser environment (where `window` is already defined).

Comment: I like this approach!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an IntelliJ editor, under

- Preferences/Settings

  - Javascript

    - Code Quality Tools

      - JSHint

        - Predefined (at bottom), click *Set*

You can type in anything, for instance `console:false`, and it will add that to the list (.jshintrc) as well - as a global.

Answer (score 2):

To fix this error when using [the online JSHint implementation](http://jshint.com/):

- Click "CONFIGURE" (top of the middle column on the page)
- Enable "jQuery" (under the "ASSUME" section at the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do the following,

```
const $ = window.$
```

to avoid it throwing linting error.