# Express: $ not found from Jade file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, jshint

I'm creating a web application using the Express framework and Jade.

In one of my Javascript files, it can not find `$`. But I used script tags in the Jade file to include jQuery. jQuery is also installed in my node_modules folder.

This is my Jade file:

```
extends layout

block content
    script(src='/javascripts/vendor/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/vendor/jquery.validate.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/validate.js')
    .....
```

This is my JavaScript file (validate.js):

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#signupForm').validate({
    ....
    });

});
```

I get the following error from JSHint:

```
 public/javascripts/validate.js
  1 |$(document).ready( function() {
     ^ '$' is not defined.
  3 |    $('#signupForm').validate({
         ^ '$' is not defined.
```

Comment: view source of page. and open jquery link...it might be path issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your global variables by configuration, or `jshint` will try to treat `$` as a local variable.

And you don't have a `$` local variable.

You can write a comment in the file

```
/*global $:false */
```

or create a `.jshintrc` to avoid this issue.

```
"globals": {
    "$": false,
    "jQuery": false
}
```

Comment: You can write a comment in the file or create a `.jshintrc`:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852765/jshint-strict-mode-and-jquery-is-not-defined